TP-Link Archer TBE550E on Ubuntu?
I wanted to switch my main desktop over to Linux now.
Everything works as intended except the wifi. I have the TP-Link Archer TBE550E and wondering if it is an easy fix for this. Or is it simply not gonna work?
I'm on Ubuntu 24.04.
I haven't looked far since I don't know what to look for. But as of what I saw graphic wise it's not there. so no wifi at all.
I have enabled onboard wifi now but would like to use the extension card since the onboard doesn't work when switching to Windows.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f5e00000-f5ffffff memory:f6000000-f6007fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: e8:9c:25:de:ce:da
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:38 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f6500000-f650ffff memory:f6510000-f6513fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8852BE PCIe 802.11ax Wireless Network Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: wlp11s0
       version: 00
       serial: a8:41:f4:2b:4a:e2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_8852be driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:110 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f6400000-f64fffff


What version of Ubuntu are you using? What have you done to troubleshoot this so far? Please edit the question and add this info. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Kernel modules (aka drivers) are specific to a kernel, but we don't know what Ubuntu product/release you're using, thus what kernel stack options exist for you yet... so we're somewhat limited. Next the kernel modules (drivers) are built for chipsets, not brand/model of the device.. so look what is in your TPL TBE550E device and go from there..  https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos maybe useful to you; but we need product/release details to be specific

Fix for what? WHat are you seeing? What works? What doesn't work? How does it fail? Please [edit] your question, tell us what is happening and what you did. Also, do you have TP-Link Archer TBE550E or are you asking us if you have it? That question mark is confusing.

Hey :)
I have change my original post! :) Hope this helps to find out what to do. :-)
